# Synopsys Synthesis with underlying modules as gate libraries

Tags: verilog, design, synthesis, compiler

I am trying to synthesize my Verilog modules into 1 top module which contains all the modules extracted into 1 top module.

With setting -hierarchy option in write_file, I get all the modules separately. 
I am not really sure if I explained it properly as I am quite new to this.

Comment: Could you check your `compile` or `compile_ultra` command? There may be a switch that disables ungrouping.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, simply replacing compile with compile_ultra did the trick.

Comment: Many years since I used synopsys but if I recall correctly the command to remove the hierarchy was "ungroup -all -flatten".

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed by the `compile_ultra` command as mentioned in the comments. Here is some explanation.

If the `compile` command is used, ungrouping is disabled by default. So it should be enabled explicitly.

```
compile -ungroup_all
```

On the contrary, auto ungrouping is enabled by default if the `compile_ultra` command is used. No additional option is required in this case.

```
compile_ultra
```